# Solidity: How can I access a variable dynamically by name?

Tags: variables, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

Is there a way to access variables in solidity using another variable?

Something like this:

```
contract Test {
    uint age;
    string varAge = "age";

    function setAge() public {
        // varAge should be able to access age variable
       ${varAge} = 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it like that? Can you specify the use case? Maybe some other clean solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It's not like PHP.

The closest thing I can think of is having a mapping like `mapping(string=>uint) myMap;`.  Then you can do stuff like `myMap["abc"] = 123;`

You could also do this...

```
uint key = "abc";
myMap[key] = 123;
```